Report quota of a XFS filesystem mounted with NFS
I have setup quota on an XFS filesystem and users can run this on that server to get their quota report:
xfs_quota -c 'quota -hu user' /xfs_partition

However I would like users to be able to retrieve the quota usage of that system directly from their machine on which this partition is mounted via NFS, because this serveur is not easily accessible.
How can I achieve this ?

The NFS v4 protocol specifies attributes to query the quota: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5661#section-5.8.2.28. However, linux client doesn’t implement it, as quota is not associated with a user or a group.
As a solution, you can try to use rquota https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/quota/quota-tools.git/, which requires and additional rquotad service to run on the host.

Thanks for your answer but it seems XFS filesystems are not supported https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/rpc.rquotad.8.html#:~:text=version%20%202%20%20%20quota%2C-,non%2DXFS%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filesystems,-)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20quota.user

Actually, it looks the other way around. XFF is the primary supported file system. All others must apply some kind of workarounds.

Ooooh no sorry actually rpc.rquotad was not running on the XFS server... I launched it and now I can get the quota on clients by simply running quota -s !
